# How to scroll android WebView inside ScrollView to caret position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have a `WebView`(width matchParent, height - wrapContent) inside `ScrollView`. Under and above this `ScrollView` other fixed elements.
I am use `WebView` as rich editor

```
<body>
    <div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
</body>
```

When I type a long text сaret hiding under keyboard.
Is any suggestion how to keep caret visible?